# Como executar requisições em ordem?

Tags: java, android

Faço 3 requisições seguidas, porém elas são disparadas por ordem de processamento, não de forma síncrona, como posso resolver isso?

```
...

//botão pressionado
// primeira requisição

ivUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             /* auto completes */

            txt_estados = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                    findViewById(R.id.txt_estado);
            txt_cidades = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                    findViewById(R.id.txt_cidade);
            txt_bairros = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                    findViewById(R.id.txt_bairro);

            final String estado = txt_estados.getText().toString().trim();
            final String cidade = txt_cidades.getText().toString().trim();
            final String bairro = txt_bairros.getText().toString().trim();
            final String metrosQ = txt_metrosQ.getText().toString().trim();
            final String quartos = txt_quartos.getText().toString().trim();
            final String garagens = txt_garagens.getText().toString().trim();
            final String cep = txt_cep.getText().toString().trim();
            final String complemento = txt_complemento.getText().toString().trim();
            final String preco = txt_preco.getText().toString().trim();
            final String descricao = txt_descricao.getText().toString().trim();
            final String map = txt_map.getText().toString().trim();

            final RadioGroup Rdtipo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rd_tipo);
            int ntipo = Rdtipo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


            if (ntipo == R.id.Apartamento) {
                tipo = "Apartamento";
            } else if (ntipo == R.id.Barracao) {
                tipo = "Barracão";
            }else if (ntipo == R.id.Residencial) {
                tipo = "Residêncial";
            }else if (ntipo == R.id.Terreno) {
                tipo = "Terreno";
            }else if (ntipo == R.id.Kitinete) {
                tipo = "Kitinete";
            }

            final RadioGroup RdtipoNeg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rd_tipoNeg);
            int ntipoNeg = Rdtipo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


            if (ntipoNeg == R.id.A) {
                tipoNeg = "A";
            } else if (ntipoNeg == R.id.C) {
                tipoNeg = "C";
            }

            final String idUser = "51"; // <-- aqui o id do usuario

            final MyCommand myCommander = new MyCommand(getApplicationContext());

            try{

                String url = "http://a4da1ea4.ngrok.io/upVariasImgs/solicitarAvaliacao.php";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        idImovel = response;


                        responseList.add(response);

                        cadImgs(); <-- chamo a segunda requisição

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao fazer upload da imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("metrosQ", metrosQ);
                        params.put("quartos", quartos);
                        params.put("garagens", garagens);
                        params.put("cep", cep);
                        params.put("complemento", complemento);
                        params.put("descricao", descricao);
                        params.put("mapa", map);
                        params.put("estado", estado);
                        params.put("cidade", cidade);
                        params.put("bairro", bairro);
                        params.put("tipo", tipo);
                        params.put("tipoNeg", tipoNeg);
                        params.put("preco", preco);
                        params.put("idUser", idUser);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                myCommander.add(stringRequest);

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao fazer upload da imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            myCommander.execute();








        }
    });
}
```

ao pressionar o botão ivUpload, é disparada a primeira requisição, onde é gravado o imóvel no banco e retornado seu id por json

```
//segunda requisição
public void cadImgs() {
    final MyCommand myCommand = new MyCommand(getApplicationContext());


    for(String imagePath: imageList){
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = PhotoLoader.init().from(imagePath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
            final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);


            String url = "http://a4da1ea4.ngrok.io/upVariasImgs/upload.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao fazer upload da imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("image", encodedString);
                    params.put("idImo", idImovel);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            myCommand.add(stringRequest);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao fazer upload da imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    myCommand.execute();
    somaId(); <-- está executando antes do loop acima
}


//terceira requisição
public void somaId(){
    ...
}
```

logo após eu pego esse id para a segunda requisição, método cadImgs(), que é disparado na resposta json da primeira requisição, até aí ele segue a ordem, porém a segunda requisição está dentro de um loop

por esse motivo não chamei a terceira função somaId() na resposta do servidor e sim depois que o loop terminasse, oque faz com que ele quebre essa ordem, e execute a função somaId, antes do loop

Comment: Só você fazer a próxima requisição somente depois de obter a resposta da primeira, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Atualizei o código em ordem, mas persiste o problema, não tenho ideia do que possa ser.

Comment: Mas qual é o problema, se você não colocar na sua pergunta, não tem como resolve-lo? Qual erro está dando?

Comment: @AckLay é justamente a ordem, faço 3 requisições para um servidor, mas elas tem de ser em ordem pois uma depende da outra, a primeira pego um id que uso na segunda e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Tem como você colocar a ordem que deve ser feita aqui nos comentários? É na ordem de inserção no código? É quando você clica no botão?

Comment: Veja se isso faz sentido para você? É exatemente o que quiz dizer no primeiro comentário: https://gist.github.com/cleidimarviana/cf74bc5f6e1c9e0e936b5519f60703e3

Comment: expliquei agora a ordem e ações no código

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56279/discussion-between-ack-lay-and-felipe-duarte).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que é percebível então, uma requisição é dependente da outra. Para que funcione na ordem corretamente, você deve chamar a próxima requisição somente se a primeira requisição já retornou algum resultado. Como está funcionando de modo assíncrono, sendo executado em modo de processamento, não possui um tempo determinado para finalizar qualquer tipo de consulta.

Um exemplo de solução do problema é você chamar uma segunda requisição dentro do seu `StringRequest`, que no caso, só será executado no término da primeira requisição. Veja

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String> () {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(String response) {

   // só será chamada a segunda requisição aqui dentro, pois já terá obtido a  resposta
   // da primeira requisição
   chamaSegundaRequisicao();
   }
}
```